# IF ELSE not working on SQL / MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

The script for checking multiple condition on SQL as follow, which I have tried.

```
BEGIN
IF  @total == 7 THEN
UPDATE some_table SET time = '09:55' where warehouse_id=@code;
UPDATE some_table SET enable = 0 where warehouse_id=@code;
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE warehouse_id= @code;
END IF
END
```

Here the value of @total is 7 but the script is not able to executing and says

> [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'IF @total == 7 THEN' at line 2

Comment: Did you write the `if else` in sp?

Comment: Is this in a stored procedure or trigger or something like that?  Because you need a shell around that. Otherwise it will not work

Comment: Is "7" an int? Where do you set `@total`? And you should do `=` and not `==`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mysql `IF ... ELSE` only support for `stored procedure` or `trigger`

You can try to move logic `@total = 7` in `where` caluse.

```
UPDATE some_table SET time = '09:55' where warehouse_id=@code and @total = 7;
UPDATE some_table SET enable = 0 where warehouse_id=@code and @total = 7;
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE warehouse_id= @code and @total = 7;
```

Comment: I think yes may that is the issue

Comment: No problem glad to help

Answer (score 0):

you should change the equal operator to = , it will be like this :

IF @total = 7 THEN ..

Comment: Same anwser posted 4 min ago